# Issue With Team Foundation Build Service Events Custom View

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent

On our TFS 2010 build boxes there is a custom event view called Team Foundation Build Service Events. I think it's created when the build service is first installed (maybe there are other conditions?). In any event, the problem I am having is that this custom view is getting recreated, so that now the event view looks something like this:

- Custom Views

  - Administrative Events

    - Team Foundation Build Service Events
    - Team Foundation Build Service Events_1
    - Team Foundation Build Service Events_2

My question is, has anyone else ran into this and is there a way to stop it from happening? As far as I can tell it isn't causing any problems. It just seems untidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm I have this issue as well. It is an annoyance, however you can simply delete the duplicated filters manually. If it bothers you can submit a bug on [**Microsoft Connect**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and hope for a fix or at least a response from the product team.

[image: build events]